# Formula for number of non-negative integer valued vectors ($x_1, x_2,...,x_r$) satisfying the equation $x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_r = n$

Tags: combinatorics

I am reading "A First Course in Probability" by Sheldon Ross and I saw this formula for the above problem:

$C(n+r-1, r-1)$

I have understood how the formula for positive integer solutions is derived but not this one. So it would be great if some one could help me with an explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution of the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_r = n$$ corresponds to a choice of where to place $r - 1$ addition signs in a row of $n$ ones.

For example, if we have the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 7$$
the solution $(3, 0, 4)$ corresponds to the choice
$$1 1 1 + + 1 1 1 1$$
while the solution $(2, 4, 1)$ corresponds to the choice 
$$1 1 + 1 1 1 1 + 1$$

Since introducing $r - 1$ addition signs in a row of $n$ ones yields $n + r - 1$ symbols, of which $r - 1$ are addition signs. Thus, the number of ways of placing $r - 1$ addition signs in a row of $n$ ones is 
$$\binom{n + r - 1}{r - 1}$$

Comment: "The number of ways we can place r−1 addition signs in a row of n ones is n+r-1 C r-1" where did that n+r-1 come from? If we write n 1s we have only n+1 choices for placing the + sign.

Comment: I have edited my answer.  The key point is that adding $r - 1$ addition signs to the row of $n$ ones gives you $n + r - 1$ symbols, of which $r - 1$ are addition signs.  Equivalently, $n$ of the $n + r - 1$ are ones, so the number of possible solutions is $$\binom{n + r - 1}{r - 1} = \binom{n + r - 1}{n}$$

Answer (score 0):

This argument is quite standard, people will start calling "stars and bars" here.

Think of $n$ units $\def\b{\bullet}\b$ and $r-1$ plus symbols to be arranged on a line to represent the sum, so $\b\b++\b\b\b\b+\b+$ would have $n=6$ and $r=5$, and represent $2+0+4+1+0=6$. This representation makes it clear that there are $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}=\binom{n+r-1}n$ solutions.